# Encrypt strings in strings.xml and still be able to use them in layouts xml files?

Tags: android, string, encryption, android-resources

Is there any way to encrypt strings in strings.xml and be able to reference them from xml layout files using the ussual format @string/name?.

Is there any possibility to get in the middle of the string retrieval and decrypt it before the view pointing to @string/name gets the real string?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how about storing encrypted strings in xml and decryption-key somewhere else, and decrypt at runtime

Comment: I need to keep the strings in strings.xml, it is a requirement (don't know if this is what you mean by "in xml" or you mean a custom xml file). Another requirement is not to lose the possibility to use the @string/name way to point to strings in xml layouts. I was hoping there could be any way to replace the default resource provider by a custom one that could do all the decryption work when asked for a string.

Comment: there is no provided solution in android, you have to built a custom solution

Comment: Ok, but is there any way to integrate my custom solution in the android workflow to retrieve strings the way I need. I have been searching ways to override default resource manager, etc... but haven't been able to find any.

Comment: @Notbad yes, keep strings in strings.xml only, don't encrypt the @string/name, but encrypt the value

Comment: @SarthakMittal, yes but how to handle de decryption transparently?

Comment: you can,for example, store decryption key in your persistent storage and decrypt whatever string you are using at runtime

Comment: Yes, you're right, but what about if I want to use this string in a layout through @string/name. I would like that the view receives the string in decrypted format not encrypted.

Comment: yeah u would surely want that :)
one way would be to only initialize strings at runtime.
another way would be to extend `View` class and simply decrypt the string and add it again to the view, extend any view with this customview.

Comment: @SarthakMittal: you're right again, but I think I have found a more general solution that do not involve changing any client code. Using LayoutInflater.Factory or Factory2. I have to check that first... Do you have any experience with them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155583/discussion-between-sarthak-mittal-and-notbad).